# php - Merging 2 Objects without casting in Yii2

Tags: php, yii

Good Morning,

I have 2 function in my model (BaseData.php) where each function returns an object.

In my EditorController.php, i will call these functions.

```
$obj1 = BaseData::getRestrictedTemplate($categoryTitle);
$obj2 = BaseData::getCommonCategory($categoryTitle);
```

What i need is to merge these 2 objects.. i tried `array_merge` function by doing this..

```
$query = (object)(array_merge((array)$obj1, (array)$obj2));
```

with this, it is merge. But what happened is it casted the object into `stdClass` instead of `yii/db/Query`

How can i do this without changing the object `yii/db/Query`..
Please Help. Thanks.

Comment: add sample dump for both objects

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = (object)(array_merge((array)$obj1, (array)$obj2));
```

This will create a stdClass Object from array.
Now in order to create the yii/db/Query Object again pass this object to the yii/db/Query Constructor.

```
$query = (object)(array_merge((array)$obj1, (array)$obj2));
$query = new yii/db/Query($query);
```

Note : This only works when both the objects are of same class or else you will lose methods or get unknown attribute errors.For that you have to loop through the array and assign its required key and value to the object of the class.

```
$array = (object)($mergedArray);
$object = new yii/db/Query();
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
  $object->$key = $value;
}
```